# How to break line after dot in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, line-breaks

For Example I have a text file like this:

```
Example sentence1.Example sentence2.Example sentence3.Example sentence4.
```

I want to make it like that:

```
Example sentence1.
Example sentence2.
Example sentence3.
Example sentence4.
```

How can i do this in notepad++?

Comment: Find what - `.`, replace with `.\r\n`. Search mode: extended

Comment: @NileshPatil: This case is much easier, and does not need a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks mate. It works. I was trying it in regular expression as mode.

Comment: @NileshPatil I've already tried that but It didn't work for me. Idk why.

Comment: `],\s*` regex matches a literal `]` followed with `,` and 0+ whitespaces incl. a newline. That will match texts matching that pattern everywhere in your document. (so, it is only good to remove "],  "-like strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and use

*Find what*: `.`
 *Replace with*: `.\r\n`
 *Search mode*: `Extended`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this you can replace all `" . "` with `". new line"`.

```
Find : "."
Replace : ".\r\n"
Search Mode : "Extended"
```

Hope it will help.